How to make shortcuts layout independent in KDE 6 / plasma 6 running wayland?
I've set Meta+1, Meta+2,... shortcuts to switch virtual desktops - my muscle-memorized workflow for years.
However, after keyboard language layout change, 1 becomes +, which overrides this shortcut to be Zoom In.
Is it possible make KDE (Plasma 6, Wayland) treat shortcuts, as if it was always the English (US) layout?
